# changing css background with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, styles

Just as a heads up, I'm new to javascript...
I'm trying to do the following:

HTML: Got a `<body id="example>` and a hidden counter `<input id="counter" value="1">`

and the following javascript (passing 1 or -1 thru the function):

```
function changeBackground(val) {
    "use strict";
    var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("counter").value, 10) + val;

    if (n > 15) {
        n = 1;
    }

    if (n < 1) {
        n = 15;
    }

    document.getElementById("counter").value = n;

    var newBgImage = "\"url(\'../exampleFolder/exampleImg" + n + ".jpg\') no-repeat center center fixed\"";

    document.getElementById("example").style.background = newBgImage;
}
```

I can't seem to get the background to change to the next image in the folder I'm pointing to from "exampleImg1" to "exampleImg2" and so on.

I tested this with an `alert(newBgImage)` to make sure I was escaping my quotes properly and I am, or at least I think so (Also, this tells me it's breaking down at the last line of code).

I know I can do this by changing class names instead and have separate classes in the CSS but my CSS would be a lot cleaner doing it this way AND I tested that just to see and it wouldn't even update `style.className`.

Not sure what what's going wrong.

Comment: Follow up question: When I set my filepath within the function I created, where is it actually being triggered from? the js file where it's stored, the html file where it's implemented, or the CSS? 

if js or css, the path should be ../example/img2.jpg so that it starts at the site root, correct?

if html, then it would just go down  example/img2.jpg?

Comment: Update: I able to achieve my desired result with `document.body.className = "exampleImg" + n;` don't know why that differs from `document.getElementById().className`or why `.style` isn't working yet (if someone knows this would be my preference so I'd appreciate any additional help). Thanks for the help so far @robert @maesbenjamin @rambo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually trying to set two different properties over there. One is the background and the other one is the backgroundPosition. So you need to split it into 2.

```
var newBgImage = "url('../exampleFolder/exampleImg" + n + ".jpg')"
document.getElementById("example").style.background = newBgImage;
document.getElementById("example").style.backgroundPosition = "no-repeat center center fixed"
```

Or you can just not set the backgroundPosition if it was already set in HTML.

Comment: still quitting at the alert. which is coming up as desired:

e.g.  "url('../exampleFolder/exampleImg2.jpg')"

Comment: @Jeronimo the alert should show url('../exampleFolder/exampleImg2.jpg'), notice the missing quotes in the URL

Comment: doesn't it need quotes around the entire property being set in js? just trying to follow syntax I found here at [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp), if that's not correct just let me know, thanks

Comment: @Jeronimo of course it needs them in the JS, but in your post you have 2 sets one needed by JS and the other which you where escaping which where not necessary. The message in the alert should not show any ". See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/toby3105/sbf7z6by/) for example

Comment: thanks, that worked! I was thinking I'd have to supply those quotes, since that would be part of the literal code I was trying to replace with the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works

```
function changeBackground(val) {
"use strict";
var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("counter").value, 10) + val;

if (n > 15) {
    n = 1;
}

if (n < 1) {
    n = 15;
}

document.getElementById("counter").value = n;

var newBgImage = "\"url('../exampleFolder/exampleImg" + n + ".jpg') no-repeat           center center fixed\"";

document.getElementById("example").style.background = newBgImage;
}
```

Comment: didn't unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The background should be a string. In alert are you getting something like this "url(\'../exampleFolder/exampleImg" + n + ".jpg\') no-repeat center center fixed" ?

if yes then style property would become:

```
style="background: "url('../exampleFolder/exampleImg" + n + ".jpg') no-repeat center center fixed""
```

this doesn't works because it's not the way.

Since this is already string what you need to do is like the following:

```
var newBgImage = "url('../exampleFolder/exampleImg" + n + ".jpg') no-repeat center center fixed";

document.getElementById("example").style.background = newBgImage;
```

This would resolve your issue.

Comment: no the variable is doing what I want (editing the filepath from exampleImg1.jpg to exampleImg2.jpg), its just not triggering the desired result

Comment: I am not saying that the path doesn't changes, what i mean is that you have got url inside quotes in the style, that doesn't works.

Comment: is [this syntax at w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp "w3school") not correct? this is what I'm trying to achieve.